# Change button color based on text fields

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 app that I'm working on. One of the pages is a login page with 2 text fields for username and password. I have a submit button at the bottom of the page. I have the styling already set up for the button, what I'm trying to do is make it so the button is my grey color I have set up when there is nothing in the text fields, when there is a value in both text field, the button will change color. How can I accomplish this with JavaScript? Here is what I've tried, but it just throws an error:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uName, #pWord").value(function () {
        if ($("#uName, #pWord").is(null)) {
            $("#submitBtnNormal").removeClass('on');
        } else {
            $("#submitBtnNormal").addClass('on');
        };
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help in advance! I'm really no good with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uName, #pWord").change(function () {
        if (!$("#uName").val().length && !$("#pWord").val().length) {
            $("#submitBtnNormal").removeClass('on');
        } else {
            $("#submitBtnNormal").addClass('on');
        };
    });
});
```

There is no event called `value`. You want to capture the event `change` which fires when you edit the text of the input fields.

Comment: Do I need to label the div with uName and pWord, or do i need to set up the @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { id = "uName" }) and for the pWord as well?

Comment: @Skrubb - The input text fields need to have those ids not the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the method you're trying to use is `val`, not `value`. Secondly, you need to run your code under an event such as `keyup`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uName, #pWord").keyup(function () {
        if (!$("#uName").val() || !$("#pWord").val()) {
            $("#submitBtnNormal").removeClass('on');
        } else {
            $("#submitBtnNormal").addClass('on');
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Js Script

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uName, #pWord").change(function () {
        if ($("#uName").val()!='' && $("#pWord").val()!='') {

            $("#submitBtnNormal").removeClass('on');
        } else {
            $("#submitBtnNormal").addClass('on');
        };
    });
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5U33b/3/)**